# The theme is not work for DialogFragment in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

I created customized style for buttons in Android. Those styles perfectly work for Activity and Fragments but it didn't work for `DialogFragment`

```
<style name="AppTheme.BlueButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/text_white</item>
</style>
```

I used the below UI button design for both Fragment and DialogFragment

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BlueButton" />
```

Comment: Try to use Theme.Translucent as a parent and inherit your custom theme in it and it works fine.

Comment: Mr.Andy Developer I'm using Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored this parent for providing material effect (Ripple effect) for my button. Also why above mentioned style was not works